# Is it safe to delete "Miscellaneous Files" of WhatsApp?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, storage

Based on an earlier [Q&A](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/526336-storage-miscellaneous-files-safe-delete.html), is it safe to delete "Miscellaneous Files" of WhatsApp?

<sub>"**safe**" as in that it won't delete anything you might regret deleting (like photos, etc which haven't been backed up elsewhere).</sub>

<sub>--- *click image to enlarge* ---</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Doesn't your Android list the files/directories accounted into "Miscellaneous files" when you tap on that entry?

Comment: @Firelord No, it does not.

Comment: Downvoting without explaining why is not all too helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it is not.

<sub>If you want to [clear storage space on your internal storage](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21068307), you may **copy-and-paste** your WhatsApp **media** folder to another place, *like* your **SD card**; then **delete** the folder's contents...</sub>